# Packery + Infinitescroll + imagesLoaded = not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I've been trying to get Packery and infinitescroll jquery plugins working, however for some reason the new elements appear on top of each other.

I was directed to the imagesloaded plugin, however for some reason it seems to overlay elements on top of one another. I applied a fix for the Smart Scroll plugin for jQuery 1.9 (https://github.com/lukeshumard/smartscroll/pull/2) however, I believe the problem lies with imagesloaded and packery.

My script looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // declaring variables
        var $sidebar        = $("#sidebarHolder"),
            $sidebarwidth   = $sidebar.width(),
            $window         = $(window),
            $windowheight   = $window.height(),
            $offset         = $sidebar.offset(),
            $topPadding     = $("#sitewide").height(),
            $container      = $('#container.clearfix');

        // making sure the sidebar stays the right size when it's resized
        $(window).on("resize",function () {
            $("[role=sidebar]").width($sidebarwidth).show();
            $("#sidebarHolder,[role=sidebar]").height($windowheight + 20);
        }).resize();

        // scroll 'stick to the top' function
        $(window).on("scroll",function() {
            if ($window.scrollTop() > $offset.top) {
                $sidebar.addClass('sticky');
            }else{
                $sidebar.removeClass('sticky');
            }
        }).scroll();

        $container.packery({
            itemSelector:'article.item',
            columnWidth:"div.grid-sizer",
            rowHeight:"div.grid-sizer",
            gutter:"div.gutter-sizer",
            transitionDuration:'0.2s'
        });

        $container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector:'div.paginate',
            nextSelector:'div.paginate a.next',
            itemSelector:'article.item',
            loading:{
                finishedMsg:'No more pages to load.'
            }
        },
        function(newElements) {
            $(newElements).imagesLoaded(function(){
                $container.packery('appended', newElements);
            });
        });

    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

If necessary I can set up a jsbin or codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with Chrome Canary, as it's working in other browsers...